# Determining if similar string exists or not in an array using Levenshtein distance

Tags: python, ruby, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I have an array of strings called referenceArray for example. I now have a string str. I want to check if any element in referenceArray is similar to str. I can calculate the Levenshtein distance between each element of referenceArray and str, and pick the element with the minimum distance.
But,the problem with this approach is i also need to know if none of the elements in referenceArray are similar to str.So in that case picking the one with minimum L distance would be wrong.

For example,

```
referenceArray = ['saint louis','new york']
str='st. louis'
```

In this case i pick `'saint louis' since it has minimum L distance of 4.`

But if `str='toronto'`, the one with `minimum L distance is 'new york'`, but the strings are ofcourse totally different. How can i determine if none of the elements in referenceArray match str or if there is a similar string ?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about setting some threshold of acceptable distance? Say, you accept the string with minimal distance only if this distance is lower than `10` or `sqrt(len(str))` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting an upper threshold of `len(str)/x`, where x is an appropriate constant. I would try with an x of 2-4.

Try it out with some sample input, and see what suits you best.